# Why should I use the Salesforce beta site?

Tags: discussion

I have several questions on the Salesforce beta StackExchange (you can see my profile [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10282/contactmatt)). As nice as it is to have a StackExchange dedicated to Salesforce, the traffic is *much* less than what I would get for tagging questions under the Salesforce tag in StackOverflow.

**Questions:**

- Why should I continue using the [Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)? It's
     nice to contribute to a beta StackExchange, but when it comes down
     to it I want questions answered quickly, and with more than one answer,
     which is what I'm typically getting on the site.
- Can I start asking my questions on StackOverflow under the Salesforce tag? Or will they be moved to the Salesforce Exchange?

Comment: There is an overlap. Any *programming problem* question about Salesforce is on-topic on Stack Overflow, and will remain so. But I'm sure there are other aspects around the product that are *not* directly programming related, and those would be migrated to Salesforce.SE.

Comment: For now less people post into salesforce stackexchange, but if you want to build and grow salesforce community in stackexchange please start/keep using https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. I also start to use it, soon or later the traffic will increase.